# Prestashop Bitnami link css and js files only with the default theme, why?

Tags: javascript, css, xampp, prestashop, bitnami

Good morning dears,

I had installed the Prestashop Bitnami on localhost (with XAMPP) and all works good. 
BUT!
I have a theme (elena, Velathemes) have good feedbacks, and it work very well on my live store (prestashop 1.6.1.4) and when i try to install the same one on the localhost prestashop (1.6.1.5 !!!) don't find any CSS or Js (Firebug error log show nothing strange, i attached a screenshot however).

I tried to update Prestashop, and it improved a little bit.. some CSS appear but the most ones no..

The back office works good, the deafult theme too.

I had install it with the .zip file on the BO

Someone have any idea where i mistake?

Thank you so much

[image: error log]

Comment: Do you have error reporting enabled?

Comment: "i attached a screenshot however" where so?

Comment: sorry, you can find it above now

Comment: No one can help me?

Comment: disable caching and set smarty recompiling. Something changed?

Comment: Yess man, i did it and it work! 

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go on the BO and:

- Disable caching (when designing is better)
- Regenerate Thumbnails
- Force the HTML compilation

Answer (score 0):

You may have configured shop wrongly. In back office go to Preferences -> SEO& URLs and do the following changes and save the changes.

> Shop Domain: **localhost:8080**
>
> SSL Domain: **localhost:8080**
>
> Base URI: **/preshtashop/**

Then clear your cache and look again.

Answer (score 0):

You have cached all.css file on your screenshot. Please refresh the cache by "Advanced parameters->Performance->Clear cache"

Then please check paths of your js scripts, css files in modules, theme files. If no links in result html please check paths and real css and js locations.